# How to make insert custom query in spring data jpa by using @Query annotation

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using mssql and spring data JPA, I want to insert new records to a table by using custom `@Query` annotation.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customers, String>{


    @Modifying
    @Query("insert into Customers values (?1 , ?2)")
    public void saveCutomer(int custId, Customer cust);

}
```

Its giving error,

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found 'values' near line 1, column 23 [insert into Customers values (?1 , ?2)]

I tried below also, same error.

```
@Modifying
    @Query("insert into Customers select ?1 , ?2")
    public void saveCutomer(int custId, Customer cust);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do that using JPQL. You have batch DELETE and UPDATE but that's it.

Your options are:

**1)** Mark the query as native if you really make explicit insert (not recommended unless you intend to use some database-specific syntax not supported by JPQL.

**2)** Use standard `save(Entity)` method on your repository which is of course preferable.

Comment: i tried the below, its working

@Query(value="insert into Customers values (?1 , ?2)", nativeQuery = true)

i am not using save(Entity) because i am using ms sql and i am trying to keep all data in a single column.

any idea, how to do this??

I am using Angular 8 for the UI.

Comment: You have to stick with the native then

Comment: thanks for your time, i am getting below error while inserting into mssql,

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Customers' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.